# How to implement RLS in Metabase Free Edition

Tags: metabase

I'm using Metabase's free edition, and I'm aware that Row-Level Security (RLS) is not available in this version. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to detect the email of the logged-in user within a dashboard and use it as a variable in my queries.

I want to implement some level of user-specific data filtering in my dashboards. Is there a workaround or a specific approach to achieve this in Metabase Free Edition? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I experimented with creating user-specific variables within Metabase dashboards to see if I could manually filter data based on the logged-in user's email.